# Can I add a badge to a Flutter ListTile that is not the leading or trailing widget?

Tags: flutter, listview

[image]

I have a list in my flutter app which uses ListView.builder, similar to the picture above. I am able to add a leading widget and trailing widget.

What I want to do is add an additional badge such as the ones in the picture. Is this possible with ListTiles? Or is there another way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please modify this code.

```
ListTile(
               leading: Icon(Icons.add),
               title: Text('John judah',),
               trailing: Row(children: [
               Icon(Icons.star),
               Icon(Icons.right),
                ],),
            ),
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work - I get this 'tileWidth != trailingSize.width'. I think it makes the tile too wide, any idea how I could prevent this?

Comment: It works as a column, so if I can't use a Row I will use a Column

Comment: So, instead of Row you can also wrap both the items in Wrap widget. @MrHarvey

Answer (score 1):

[Muhammad Tameem Rafay's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64778266/can-i-add-a-badge-to-a-flutter-listtile-that-is-not-the-leading-or-trailing-widg#comment116199701_64784223) is the correct answer. You can use a `Wrap()` widget like this:

```dart
ListTile(
  leading: Icon(Icons.add),
  title: Text('John judah',),
  trailing: Wrap(children: [
    Icon(Icons.star),
    Icon(Icons.right),
  ]),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Row` to put 2 widgets alongside each other like you want. This will go in the `trailing` parameter in ListTile.

Please let me know if that solves your problem!

Comment: Thanks, same as the answer by Muhammad, left a comment on his with the error this gives

Answer (score 0):

try this

```dart
ListTile(
  leading: Icon(Icons.notifications),
  title: Text('Notification'),
  trailing: Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: [
      Icon(Icons.star),
      Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
    ],
  ),
)
```